Content of JSON file is escaped
I have a JavaScript that creates and saves a JSON file which contains an array of objects:


       let  Animal = {
          legs: "",
          color: "",
        };


    let arr[];
    let me = Object.create(Animal);
    me.legs = "a";
    me.color = "b";

        arr.push(me);

    window.localStorage.setItem("example", JSON.stringify(arr));
exportA();

        function exportA()
        {
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(
                 new Blob([JSON.stringify(window.localStorage.getItem("example"), null, 2)], {
                    type: "text/json"
            }));
            a.setAttribute("download", "examplefile.json");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }



All things works fine. When I open the created file with text editor I get following output: "[{\"legs\":\"a\",\"color\":\"b\"}]" Several online validators and my browsers confirms the JSON content as valid.
My expected output is: [{"legs":"a","color":"b"}]. My question is, what do I miss to create the expected output of a list or is it just a mistake of thinking?

You're stringifying the data twice, once when you save it to localStorage, and then again after retrieving it in the Blob constructor

The problem
The problem is you stringify() twice. Once when you store it in local storage and then again when you create the Blob.
Solution
There are two possible solutions to the problem:
1st solution
Remove the JSON.stringify() call when you create the Blob and already store the string indented in the local storage using window.localStorage.setItem("example", JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2))
2nd solution
When you retrieve the string from local storage parse it first and then serialize it again with the indentation applied
const storedJson = window.localStorage.getItem("example");
const indentedJson = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(storedJson), null, 2);
const blob = new Blob([indentedJson], { type: "text/json" });
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);


Thanks,.I took the first suggestion and it works.
